# Bash - what is the point of restoring positional arguments with `set`?

Tags: bash, parameter-passing

Considering the following code to parse bash script arguments (let's say `example.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
positional=()
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    arg="$1"
    case ${arg} in
        -h|--help|\?)       show_usage;         exit 0      ;;
        -v|--verbose)       verbose=1;          shift       ;;
        -f|--file)          theFile="$2";       shift; shift;;
        *)                  positional+=("$1"); shift       ;;
    esac
done
set -- "${positional[@]}"

arg1a="${positional[0]}"; arg1b="$1" # same result, $arg1a == $arg1b
arg2a="${positional[1]}"; arg2b="$2" # same result, $arg2a == $arg2b
```

With the following call to the script:

`./example.sh pos1 -v -f toto.txt pos2`

- Before the loop, `"$1" == "pos1"` and `"$5" == "pos2"`
- After the loop, before the `set --`, `$1`, `$2` and `$5` are undefined
- After the `set --`,  `"$1" == "pos1"`and `"$2" == "pos2"`

But also, after the `set --`, `${positional[0]} == "pos1"`and `${positional[1]} == "pos2"`.

#### So, the question is : what is the actual point of using `set -- "${positional[@]}"` ?

We do can get the values of our positional arguments (with `${positional[i]}`) in the same order that it was provided, without restoring it to `$1` and `$2`. Therefore, I don't understand the point of using `set --`. If we don't use it here, then `$# -eq 0` and that's it...

Please, provide a real life example where the use of `set --` is mandatory, even with this `${positional[]}` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the 'while' loop, the 'positional' array will capture all the command line options and arguments, other than the '-v', '--verbose', '-f' and '--file' (and the parameters to the -f/--file).

At that point, the rest of the script will continue to run WITHOUT those parameters.

Possible reason for this coding is that the above block extend the original behavior of the script to include two additional options (verbose, and file), which are not supported by other parts of the script.

This can be useful, if the script will than execute another command (e.g., ls), which does not support the verbose/file options, with user provided command line arguments.

```
# Code to strip verbose/file command line options
while 
do
    ...
done
set --
# Do something above $verbose, $theFile
...
# Original script here - use any unprocessed parameters from command line
ls "$@"
```

EDIT: from comments:

With modern bash, you can use array instead of positional arguments for almost any operation. Few exceptions: the built-in: `shift`, `getopt`, work only on positional arguments

Comment: That is not really necessary here, as you can call `ls "${positional[@]}"` instead of `ls "$@"`. I'm looking for an example where the use of `set --` is necessary

Comment: With modern bash, you can use array instead of positional arguments for almost any operation. Few exceptions: the built-in: shift, getopt, work only on positional arguments

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I don't really see a scenario in which `getopt` or `shift` would have to be used after manually parsing options, but these built-in indeed require the use of `set --`. Thank you for this information.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used made use of restoring positional arguments up until now, and in fact stumbled upon this Q/A while researching.
The real benefit seems to be that you can import (source) other scripts that only know about positional params, and allow their functions to process params in the way they already know how to do it, without having to modify them or call them with a subshell.